# How to run Hadoop on a Mesos cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mesos

I am trying to set up a Apache Mesos Cluster and run Hadoop-Job on it. The documentation [here](https://github.com/mesos/hadoop)  is not at my level, so that i am not able to understand  and maybe someone here can explain me:

First should I set up a working Hadoop Cluster? Or first set up a Mesos cluster?
where do I point the slaves? in Hadoop-slaves file or registered Mesos slaves should only be used?

Answer (score 10):

The goal of Mesos is to run an abstraction for your cluster, where Hadoop would just be 1 service among others. In order for this to work, you need to first setup your Mesos cluster as the primary component, and then you can start adding services like Hadoop to this cluster using the Mesos abstraction.

There is [an excellent tutorial](http://mesosphere.io/learn/run-hadoop-on-mesos-using-installer) from Mesosphere that you should take a look at, and it explains in details how to run Hadoop on top of Mesos, so this would be a good place to start.

Alternatively, this company recently started a serviced for [Elastic Mesos](https://elastic.mesosphere.io/), similar in nature to Amazon's Elastic MapReduce. So if you want to get started quickly with Hadoop on Mesos without having to go through the pain of configuring everything, this is a good place to start.

Comment: thank you, your answer helped a lot but one more thing i got to ask. when i set up the hadoop cluster, should it be like the standard steps including passwordless ssh ability for master to slaves or does mesos have this ability already ?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a mesos cluster setup and running such that slaves show up in the Mesos WebUI, you can add hadoop to it by doing the following steps:

1. First you have to setup HDFS. Cloudera's hadoop distribution is an easy way to do so. Just follow the instructions on this [link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_4_4.html) for setting it up. This will automatically setup user accounts for you to run the MapReduce Jobs
2. You just need to have a namenode running on your master and datanode running on your slaves. Navigating to *localhost:50070* will show you that namenode is up and running and will also give a list of datanodes running. You dont need tasktrackers or jobtracker for now
3. Next for integrating hadoop on mesos go to this [github repository](https://github.com/mesos/hadoop). Clone it on your PC and follow the instruction on the Readme
4. By this time you will have a jobtracker running on your master. Navigate to *localhost:50030* to see that jobtracker is running. You don't need tasktrackers on your slaves. Mesos will automatically start them for you by using the tar file you uploaded to the HDFS

Also you can consult the Mesosphere tutorial for any doubts you have. Just don't follow all the steps there as they are not for the latest Mesos versions.

Comment: Does this tutorial set up HDFS as well?

http://mesosphere.com/docs/tutorials/run-hadoop-on-mesos-using-installer/

It is a bit confusing when they say Run Hadoop on Mesos.
Then in the Hadoop tutorial, they mention "put this file on HDFS".
Wait - isn't HDFS Hadoop?

Chicken and the egg.

I installed Mesos and Marathon on Amazon using this tutorial and it works well:
http://mesosphere.com/docs/getting-started/datacenter/install/

Now I need to add HDFS for some Spark shared file support.

Comment: Does YARN require to run hadoop job??