# Can't run spark-submit with an application jar on a Mesos cluster

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

Mesosphere did a great job on simplifying the process of running Spark on Mesos.  I am using this guide to setup a development Mesos cluster on Google Cloud Compute.

https://mesosphere.com/docs/tutorials/run-spark-on-mesos/

I can run the example that's in the guide by using `spark-shell` (finding numbers less than 10).  However, when I attempt to submit an application that otherwise works fine with Spark locally it blows up with TASK_FAILED messages (i.e. `CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 4 is now TASK_FAILED`).

Here's the command I'm using with the provided Spark Pi example.

`./spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master mesos://10.173.40.36:5050 ~/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar 100`

And the output:

```
jclouds@development-5159-d9:~/learning-spark$ ~/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master mesos://10.173.40.36:5050 ~/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar 100
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/03/22 16:44:02 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.0
15/03/22 16:44:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jclouds
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jclouds
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(jclouds); users with modify permissions: Set(jclouds)
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@development-5159-d9.c.learning-spark.internal:60301]
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 60301.
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-27fad7e3-4ad7-44d6-845f-4a09ac9cce90/blockmgr-a558b7be-0d72-49b9-93fd-5ef8731b314b
15/03/22 16:44:03 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.0 MB
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-de9ac795-381b-4acd-a723-a9a6778773c9/httpd-7115216c-0223-492b-ae6f-4134ba7228ba
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:36663
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 36663.
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://development-5159-d9.c.learning-spark.internal:4040
15/03/22 16:44:04 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/jclouds/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar at http://10.173.40.36:36663/jars/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar with timestamp 1427042644934
Warning: MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY is deprecated, use MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY instead. Future releases will not support JNI bindings via MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY.
Warning: MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY is deprecated, use MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY instead. Future releases will not support JNI bindings via MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY.
I0322 16:44:05.035423   308 sched.cpp:137] Version: 0.21.1
I0322 16:44:05.038136   309 sched.cpp:234] New master detected at master@10.173.40.36:5050
I0322 16:44:05.039261   309 sched.cpp:242] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0322 16:44:05.040351   310 sched.cpp:408] Framework registered with 20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-0019
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Registered as framework ID 20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-0019
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 44177
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager development-5159-d9.c.learning-spark.internal:44177 with 265.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, development-5159-d9.c.learning-spark.internal, 44177)
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 2 is now TASK_RUNNING
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 1 is now TASK_RUNNING
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 0 is now TASK_RUNNING
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 2 is now TASK_FAILED
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 1 is now TASK_FAILED
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 0 is now TASK_FAILED
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: reduce at SparkPi.scala:35
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 3 is now TASK_RUNNING
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 4 is now TASK_RUNNING
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (reduce at SparkPi.scala:35) with 100 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(reduce at SparkPi.scala:35)
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:31), which has no missing parents
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 3 is now TASK_FAILED
15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Blacklisting Mesos slave value: "20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-S1"
 due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
 15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 4 is now TASK_FAILED
 15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Blacklisting Mesos slave value: "20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-S0"
  due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1848) called with curMem=0, maxMem=277842493
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1848.0 B, free 265.0 MB)
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1296) called with curMem=1848, maxMem=277842493
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1296.0 B, free 265.0 MB)
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on development-5159-d9.c.learning-spark.internal:44177 (size: 1296.0 B, free: 265.0 MB)
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 5 is now TASK_RUNNING
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 100 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:31)
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 100 tasks
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 5 is now TASK_FAILED
  15/03/22 16:44:05 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Blacklisting Mesos slave value: "20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-S2"
   due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
   15/03/22 16:44:20 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I suspect it may have something to do with the **mesos slave nodes not finding the application jar**, but when I put it in HDFS and provide the URL to it, `spark-submit` tells me it will `Skip remote jar`.

```
jclouds@development-5159-d9:~/learning-spark$ ~/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master mesos://10.173.40.36:5050 hdfs://10.173.40.36/tmp/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar 100Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Warning: Skip remote jar hdfs://10.173.40.36/tmp/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:538)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

--

EDIT: Just to bring this to conclusion, `hbogert` on the spark user list pointed me in the direction of debugging the `spark` logs on one of my slave nodes and the problem was as clear as day.

`jclouds@development-5159-d3d:/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-S1/frameworks/20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-0037/executors/1/runs/latest$ cat stderr
I0329 20:34:26.107267 10026 exec.cpp:132] Version: 0.21.1
I0329 20:34:26.109591 10031 exec.cpp:206] Executor registered on slave 20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-S1
sh: 1: /home/jclouds/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-class: not found
jclouds@development-5159-d3d:/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-S1/frameworks/20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-0037/executors/1/runs/latest$ cat stdout
Registered executor on 10.217.7.180
Starting task 1
Forked command at 10036
sh -c ' "/home/jclouds/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-class" org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url akka.tcp://sparkDriver@development-5159-d9.c.learning-spark.internal:54746/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler --executor-id 20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-S1 --hostname 10.217.7.180 --cores 10 --app-id 20150322-040336-606645514-5050-2744-0037'
Command exited with status 127 (pid: 10036)`

Related:

- [How to run Hadoop on a Mesos cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939853/how-to-run-hadoop-on-a-mesos-cluster)
- http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-submit-failing-on-cluster-td8369.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing what's the stderr output in the Mesos sandbox logs, but usually you need to make sure you set the `MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY` (in `spark-env.sh`) and also the `spark.executor.uri` (in `spark-defaults.conf`) URL pointing to a Spark tar correctly.  If not you need to have spark installed at the same location in each slave.

Comment: Yes, I'm setting both `MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY` and `SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI` (`spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4`) in my `spark-env.sh`.  Everything's working fine when I connect to the mesos cluster using `spark-shell.sh`, but the question is how do I submit a Spark driver application via `spark-submit.sh` with Mesos?  I can get this working fine with Spark Standalone and YARN clusters.

Comment: To run `spark-shell.sh` you need the SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI set to your Spark binaries (i.e. on HDFS).  To run jobs via `spark-submit.sh` you also or instead need to have `spark.executor.uri` either in your driver application itself or in `spark-defaults.conf`.